# Why Bootstrap CSS class table-striped not working in asp.net?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Asp.net and bootstrap. I referenced bootstrap.min.css in my html and I have gridview control I want to style with "table table-striped" class. Visual studio intelisens seems to fail to recognize table-striped class and it's not working when the program runs. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Here's my html source:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NotDelivered.aspx.cs" Inherits="PapaBobs.NotDelivered" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class ="container">
        <div class ="form-group">
            <asp:GridView ID="notDeliveredGrid" runat="server" CssClass ="table table-hover table-striped"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current href value specifies relative path to css file and browser just cannot load it because this path doesn't exist. Update link to the following

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Also consider using [bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, for example, I don't have any problem with "table-borderless" it works fine. Intelisense shows it and bunch of other table related CSS classes with no problem but "table-striped"  is not in the list and when I type it on my own it seems to have no effect in final work